# JAXB & java.mail Java 11: Module problems

Tags: jaxb, jakarta-mail, java-11, java-module

When I converted an application, that uses jaxb & java.mail, from java 8 to java 11 I had lots of module problems that seemed intractable.

My build.gradle included:

```
compile group: 'javax.xml.bind', name: 'jaxb-api', version: '2.3.1'
compile group: 'javax.mail', name: 'mail', version: '1.4.7'
```

The module errors I got included:

```
the unnamed module reads package javax.activation from both java.activation and activation
```

I tried this but it didn't work with the same error:

```
compile (group: 'javax.xml.bind', name: 'jaxb-api', version: '2.3.1') {
    exclude group: 'javax.activation', module: 'activation'
}
compile group: 'javax.mail', name: 'mail', version: '1.4.7'
```

And I tried this which also failed:

```
compile group: 'javax.xml.bind', name: 'jaxb-api', version: '2.3.1'
compile (group: 'javax.mail', name: 'mail', version: '1.4.7') {
    exclude group: 'javax.activation', module: 'activation'
}
```

The error was:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory
```

Also tried using in gradle with various exclude statements that all failed one way or another:

```
compile (group: 'javax.xml.bind', name: 'jaxb-api', version: '2.3.1') 
compile (group: 'com.sun.xml.bind', name: 'jaxb-core', version: '2.3.0.1') 
compile (group: 'com.sun.xml.bind', name: 'jaxb-impl', version: '2.3.0.1')
```

Also got runtime error:

```
class not found com.sun.activation.registries.LogSupport
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

In the end I found that using glassfish.jaxb and jakarta.mail worked.

My build.gradle included:

```
compile(group: 'org.glassfish.jaxb', name: 'jaxb-runtime', version: '2.3.2') {
    exclude group: 'jakarta.activation', module: 'jakarta.activation-api'
}
compile group: 'com.sun.mail', name: 'jakarta.mail', version: '1.6.5'
```

My module-info.java included:

```
requires java.xml.bind;
requires jakarta.mail;
requires com.sun.xml.bind;    // needed this for jlink
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm glad you got it working.  There's definitely some problems with activation being remove from JDK 11 and with disagreement over how API jars should be handled.  I'm hoping we'll be able to fix this in the Jakarta EE 9 versions of these components.  In the future, consider filing bugs against the Eclipse projects hosting these components.

Comment: Thanks Bill. Good to see recognition of the problem, and possibility of a future solution. Good steer to file bugs but I have some basic questions: how do I know in this case which component(s) cause the problem, and how do I know who manages components in order to file bugs? I saw a confusing set of errors around xml.bind and mail and I just used gradle to look at the dependencies to see whether I could figure out the culprit - just looked like an opaque non-functioning mess to me.

Comment: You singled out activation but this looked like just one issue, and you mentioned eclipse but none of the components had a package name of of org.eclipse.xx? Sorry probably just my lack of experience here..

Comment: If you look in the jar files, or if you find them in Maven Central, you'll find a pom.xml file that should have a pointer to the project and/or source code repository where you can file bugs.  A little bit of general googling should lead you to the same place.

Comment: Understood. Thank you Bill for the pointers - much appreciated.